# mysql oledb driver

Tags: mysql, windows, oledb

how to install mysql oledb driver in local system.

please give Mysql oledb Connection string

Answer (score 0):

```
Provider=OleMySql.MySqlSource.1
```

Comment: Just as a suggestion (for future answers), providing an explanation of what you did is always helpful, even if the solution is simple.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

### .NET Solution (c#)

You need to install MySql.Data using Package-Manager...

PM>Install-Package MySql.Data

Then, in your c# code do something like this..

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Common;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

DbProviderFactory factory = new MySqlClientFactory();
DbConnection cxn = factory.CreateConnection();
cxn.ConnectionString = "server=mysqlserver;port=3306;Database=mydb;user id=myname;password=mypass;SslMode=none;Convert Zero Datetime=True";
cxn.Open();
```