# OleDb Provider for MySQL

Tags: mysql, oledb, oledbconnection

Do MySQL provides OleDb Provider?

Where I do get OleDB provider for MySQL?

I have tried over internet but not getting anything useful on MySQL official site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql oledb driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393725/mysql-oledb-driver)

Comment: @andrews They have provided OleDb Provider from non MySQL website. I need it from MySQL website itself.