# Connect to mysql using oledb without using without MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I am trying to connect Mysql database from c# using oledb

```
  OleDbConnection MyConnection;
  OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();

   MyConnection.ConnectionString = @"Provider`enter code here`=MySQLProv;" +
               " Initial Catalog=testdemo;" +
               " User ID=root; Password=''";            
   MyConnection.Open();
```

I am getting following error.

The 'MySQLProv' provider is not registered on the local machine.

What is the solution for this ?
Can anyone help me in this please....

Comment: is it present a connector with that name ? run odbcad32.exe, you should see the overall list.

Comment: What problem do you have with the MySqlClient?

Comment: Make sure the provider is installed and connection string is correct - see this issue for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393725/mysql-oledb-driver. Why not using MySQL Connector .NET in first place?